# mybatis type conversion error

Tags: java, mybatis

there is a problem i can not configure out , i have a pojo ,

```
private String userId;
private String userName;
private String password;
private String contactTel;
private String email;
```

the getter and setter is no problem,and the type in database is also varchar2 , database i use is oracle 11g,when i update a record ,there comes an error,here is the stack,some somebody can help me ,

DEBUG [http-8080-1] - Closing non transactional SqlSession [org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession@18b198d1]
org.mybatis.spring.MyBatisSystemException: nested exception is org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.PersistenceException:

#### Error updating database.  Cause: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "abcd"

#### Cause: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "abcd"

```
at org.mybatis.spring.MyBatisExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(MyBatisExceptionTranslator.java:73)
at org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate$SqlSessionInterceptor.invoke(SqlSessionTemplate.java:364)
```

Comment: which column is it? and can you include the ibatis config for the table. Also more stack trace would be nice.

Comment: problem is sovled,thanks all of you

Comment: Could you share what the problem was?

Answer (score 0):

check test condition clause and make sure that you are not comparing string with a number

eg
if test="userId!= null and userId != '' and userId != -1 "

if this is the case,put quotes around -1 to make it string